# How can i store object to mysql JSON data?

Tags: mysql, json, object

I have JSON sample from mysql like this:

```
{"a": "testA", "b": [{"b1": "testB1"}, {"b2": "testB2"}, {"b3": "testB3"}]}
```

I want to set object "b" to:

`[{"b4": "testB4"}, {"b5": "testB5"}, {"b6": "testB6"}]`

I used this query:

`UPDATE jsontest SET content = JSON_SET content, '$[0].b', '[{"b4": "testB4"}, {"b5": "testB5"}, {"b6": "testB6"}]') WHERE id = '1';`

it works but object "b" 's value turns to string.
i suppose object "b" 's value is an array.

Comment: You need to use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: JSON.parse()the respond's object "b" from mysql?..

Comment: is there a way to make mysql store this array to object "b" instead of storing a string to object "b"

Comment: Try: `UPDATE jsontest SET content = JSON_SET(content, '$.b', CAST('[{"b4": "testB4"}, {"b5": "testB5"}, {"b6": "testB6"}]' AS JSON)) WHERE id = '1';`.

Comment: @wchiquito it works ! thank you very much!